# Magento Enterprise Associated Products

Tags: configurable-product, associated-products, ee-1.14

Magento (Enterprise 1.14) we have a configurable product that, when you check in the back end, is showing only 3 associated products. However, when you view the product on the frontend, there are 20+ associated. I am trying to edit the associated products for this product but it's not showing anything. Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Please try to reindex from admin and check.

Comment: Hi, thank you, I have run the reindexes several times but nothing showing in the backend.